# Bash & (graphviz) dot output redirection

Tags: bash, graphviz, dot

I am a Bash novice struggling to get automatic running of a dot command whenever a target file changes. I would like to have the output `.png` open in a file viewer, and have the image update on `.dot` file save.

I tried a one liner to no avail (I think there was a buffering problem, thus no output?):

```
inotifywait -m --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' -e close_write . |
awk '{print $4}' | dot $1 -Tpng -o foo.png
```

Moving to a basic Bash script, I tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="./foo.dot"
inotifywait -m --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' -e close_write "${MONITORDIR}" | while read TIME DIR EVENT FILE
do
    echo $FILE;
    dot -Tpng ${FILE} -o 'foo.png';
done
```

But a variety of problems would occur depending on use of the `-o` flag vs redirection (up to `2>&1`)*.  Usually the output file was blank.  I would prefer to avoid diving deep into bashland, but: what should I be doing differently?  Shouldn't this be a trivial thing?

<sub>* For example, `Warning: <stdin>: syntax error in line 1 near '16'`</sub>

Comment: Pipelines don't set positional arguments. You can't pipe to a command using `$1` for the pipeline input.

Comment: What gave you that warning? `dot`? Your viewer? Did `$FILE` get set correctly with that loop? If so, and that `dot` command is correct, then that `while` loop should have worked. Though when in its processing `dot` will truncate the output file I'm not sure. You might be better off using a temporary output file and then using `mv` to replace the real file once `dot` finishes.

Comment: Aside: If it starts with `#!/bin/sh`, it's a POSIX sh script, not a bash script. Bash scripts start with `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 2):

Etan's comments led to a working version:

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="./foo.dot"
inotifywait -m --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' -e close_write "${MONITORDIR}" | while read TIME DIR EVENT FILENAME
do
    echo $TIME;
    echo $DIR;
    echo $EVENT;
    echo $FILENAME;
    dot -Tpng $DIR -o 'foo.png';
done
```

Notably, there are 4 positional arguments from a bare watch statement, but variables bash sees are different:

```
me@comp:~/Projects/inotifytest$ inotifywait -m --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' -e close_write .
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
17:23 ./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE foo.dot
```

vs

```
me@comp:~/Projects/inotifytest$ sh dotwatch.sh
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
17:22
./foo.dot
CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
<Intentionally blank>
```

Editing the dotfile results in realtime graph updating.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Aside: All-uppercase variable names are reserved -- see fourth paragraph of POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace; your own variables should have at least one lower-case character in their names to avoid conflict with variables with meaning to your shell or operating system.

Comment: Aside: "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")", "${array[@]}", "a & b". Use 'single quotes' for code or literal $'s: 'Costs $5 
                US', ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words .